# How to use ipaddresses variable from vsphere_guest results in playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I want use the variable `ipaddresses` of `vsphere_guest`. I want to use the name of the virtual machine in vSphere first to get its IP address and then to run Ansible plays on that machine using the IP address.

So far I have:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "inventory_hostname"
      prompt: "Enter virtual machine name"
      private: no
      default: "ansible-test"


  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: '192.168.250.1'
    vcenter_user: 'root'
    vcenter_pass: 'pass'

  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        guest: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: vsphere_facts
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: See _Launch instances, runs some tasks_ example from [ec2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to run another play on the virtual machine for which you obtained `ipaddresses` variable (and has one IP address or it's reachable using the first IP address on the list), you can continue your playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "inventory_hostname"
      prompt: "Enter virtual machine name"
      private: no
      default: "ansible-test"

  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: '192.168.250.1'
    vcenter_user: 'root'
    vcenter_pass: 'pass'

  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        guest: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: vsphere_facts

    - name: Ensure virtual machine is in the dynamic inventory
      add_host:
        name: "{{ vsphere_facts.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] }}"
        ansible_user: _______
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: _______
        groups: virtual_machines

- name: A play to be run on the virtual machine
  hosts: virtual_machines
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Comment: `- debug: var=vsphere_facts.ipaddresses` then `- debug: var=vsphere_facts.ipaddresses[0]`

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions into the answer and rolled-back the question - it's a bit messy then if the question contains the answer. Glad it worked for you finally. Thanks for cooperation with debugging, I didn't have vSphere at the moment to test on.